# Task queue authentication from Compute Engine - "Insufficient Permission"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I am trying to use a pull queue from Compute engine VM instance using Google's python REST API library and keep getting a 403 error - "Insufficient Permission"

queue.yaml:

```
queue:
- name: queuename
  mode: pull
```

building the api client:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
task_api = build('taskqueue', 'v1beta2', credentials=credentials)
```

fetching a task:

```
lease_req = task_api.tasks().lease(project=PROJECT_NAME,
                                           taskqueue=QUEUE_NAME,
                                           leaseSecs=60 * 30,
                                           numTasks=1)
result = lease_req.execute()
```

the result is always a HttpError 403 - Insufficient Permission

VM has full cloud platform api access enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the TaskQueue from GCE by `GoogleCredentials.get_application_default`:

1. Either the server you use must have Task queue, Cloud API access scopes enabled. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gce-discussion/1aN8Aiv5F0A).
2. Or the server has to be connected to the Google account with proper rights, i.e. the proper key must be in the `/root/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` (if the process is run under another user, then the key is searched in the user home).
3. Or point the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the proper json key file (you need the `service_account` key, not the `authorized_user`).

The `service_account` key must have access to the proper scope, either `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/taskqueue` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/taskqueue.consumer`. (To generate OAuth2 credentials go to the web Google GAE Console *API Manager - Credentials*).

You have to set up the queue ACL, as well in `queue.yaml`:

```
queue:
- name: myqueue
  mode: pull
  acl:
  - user_email: myemail@myemailserver.com
  - writer_email: myemail@myemailserver.com
```

### General REST API access

You may access the TaskQueue REST API from any machine. You may load the credentials manually, too:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
# use the right scopes by the queue ACL
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/taskqueue']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('myemail.json', scopes=SCOPES)
# or
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile('myemail@myemailserver.com', '/path/to/myemail.p12', scopes=SCOPES)
```

Comment: Old question.. I have already fixed it using SignedJwtAssertionCredentials with a .pem key file and queue ACL with user_email, writer_email of the account. did not try your solution as it's not relevant for me anymore but it looks right, setting as accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that TaskQueue API is only a feature for App Engine and thus not accessible from Google Compute Engine.

Comment: TaskQueue is accessible form outside GAE by the REST API and that's what's used in the question.